# How to Cleanup a ViewModel in Mvvm Light?

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a list of items that goes to another page, That page is hooked up to a view model. In the constructor of this view model I have code that grabs data from the server for that particular item.

What I found is that when I hit the back button and choose another item fromt hat list and it goes to the other page the constructor does not get hit.

I think it is because the VM is now created and thinks it does not need a new one. I am wondering how do I force a cleanup so that a fresh one is always grabbed when I select from my list?

Comment: How do you retrieve your ViewModels? Via XAML or from code-behind?

Comment: Can't you use the locator and have a static reference that's consistent across the board?

Comment: Take a glance at the answer (in case you didnt get notification from the answer's comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue, that's how i solved it.

Have a BaseView class, override OnNavigatedTo

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        if (NavigatedToCommand != null && NavigatedToCommand.CanExecute(null))
            NavigatedToCommand.Execute(null);
    }
```

add DependencyProperty.

```
   public static readonly DependencyProperty NavigatedToCommandProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("NavigatedToCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(BaseView), null);
    public ICommand NavigatedToCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(NavigatedToCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NavigatedToCommandProperty, value); }
    }
```

On the necessary pages, add to xaml (and, of course, inherit BaseView )

```
NavigatedToCommand="{Binding OnNavigatedToCommand}"
```

In the ViewModel, make command itself

```
public RelayCommand OnNavigatedToCommand
        { get { return new RelayCommand(OnNavigatedTo); } }
```

and implement method you want to call to update list

```
public async void OnNavigatedTo()
    {
        var result = await myDataService.UpdateMyList();
        if (result.Status == OK)
            MyList = result.List;
    }
```

So, now, every time you navigate to page with list, inside of overriden OnNavigatedTo(), a NavigatedToCommand would be executed, which would execute OnNavigatedToCommand (which you set in xaml), which would call OnNavigatedTo, which would update your list.

A bit messy, but MVVM :)

EDIT: What about cleanings, they can be done in OnNavigatedFrom(), which works the same. Or OnNavigatingFrom(), which also can be useful in some cases.

Comment: Hey, chobo, do a double-check for this solution. It seems, this makes a memory leak. Though, i'm not sure - still investigating.

Comment: Although it may solve the OP's problem, it doesn't answer "how to cleanup the viewmodel".

Comment: @JeffRSon Why not? Just do all the cleanings in OnNavigatedFrom(), which works the same.

Comment: As I see it, the actual use case is too special for the general question. Maybe the title should be reworded.

Comment: @JeffRSon I just re-read the question. His problem with the list cleaning can be solved precisely by `ViewModel.OnNavigatedTo() { MyList.ReplaceWith(pulledList); } `.